# PhoneGap getJSON to call REST Service not working

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, rest, cordova

I am creating a PhoneGap application that should call some REST web service methods to get some data and to send some data to the server.

Somewhere in my program I have got the following code:

```
$.getJSON("https://mgeowiki4.iwvi.uni-koblenz.de/API/UniKoblenz/validateCredentials/SampleUser/Password",
       function(data){
             echo("data: " + data);
   })
   .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
   .error(function() { alert("error"); })
   .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Unfortunately when I execute this nothing happens. I am using Eclipse with the android emulator to test this. None of the alert messages are displayed. Even the error message is not displayed.

If I call the service in browser I get the following if the password was not correct:

```
{"passwordIsValid": "false"}
```

and the following if the password is correct:

```
{"passwordIsValid": "true"}
```

How can I get those results in my PhoneGap application?
I kind of have no clue what to do :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you [allow the ajax-endpoint in the whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)?

Whats the output of logcat?

Comment: I have now added the url to the whitelist.
This way it works :-)

There was another stupid mistake: I used "echo" in the JavaScript Code. This is no JavaScript Command. And therefore the execution stopped. I was working in PHP in parallel to working with JavaScript and somehow used the wrong command here. Thanks for the hint with logcat. This helped finding the error.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for like 6 hours and now it's fixed. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

use like this in you page, will work - [Consume Service Jquery Json](https://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/consuming-webservice-net-json-using-jquery/)